# Context Menu Order of Common File Commands - Specifically Save and Close

Tags: menu, contextual-menu

Thoughts on the order of common file commands in a context menu?

Close
Save
Save and close

or

Save
Save and Close
Close

What is more commonly used in a Context Menu? Close or Save.
Adobe apps seem to put Close first.

Comment: Is this just a general question or do you have a particular type of app that you are trying to understand the convention that is used? There may not really be an answer because different applications might have their own convention that their users are more familiar with.

Comment: This would be a web application that is designed and layout orientated app.

Comment: What do you mean by a web application that is designed and layout oriented? So something like Figma or Adobe XD?

Comment: Yes, something like that.